# Unmute microphone in Google Meet programmatically with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to create a JavaScript and inject it using a Chrome extension "User JavaScript and CSS" which can unmute the microphone on Google Meet when needed.

I'm new to this and don't know what to do. Here is an example code that does something when the space bar is pressed. Please help me to fill in this code to unmute the Google Meet microphone when the spacebar is pressed.

```
document.body.onkeyup = function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 32){
        alert("Space Bar Pressed!");  //sends an alert when space bar is pressed
        

        //code to unmute the microphone
        
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Jeniz, welcome to SO! Could you reformat your question to give away a little more information? Are you writing a plug in (web extension) or simply trying to inject javascript onto the webpage from the developer console/some other method? Edit -- you probably can't directly control the microphone, but could tie your listener to a button on the page as Burning Alcohol suggested

Comment: I'm trying to inject the code using a chrome extension called "User JavaScript and CSS". I don't know to code Java Script. I'm trying to find how to do this for a project. It would be great if you can help me do that.

Comment: You should learn Java Script before you attempt something like this.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you want to inject the script into the webpage. If so, inspect the page using Chrome and identify the mute/unmute button, such as its unique id or class name, then mock a click action after space button is hit. Try it yourself first before throwing an empty script here.

Comment: Yuh, I tried to find its id/class name. But it acts weird and changes the class name when I press the button. I'm trying to figure this out for two days. I have no clue on how to do that. Can you please help?